# ANTLR: Generating tree graph using custom types instead of CommonTree

Tags: c#, antlr, antlr3

I've already a grammar definition in ANTLR for the very simple expressions like `(a + b) * c`:

```
grammar SimpleCalc;

options {
    language=CSharp2;
    output=AST;
}

tokens {
    PLUS  = '+' ;
    MINUS = '-' ;
    MULT = '*' ;
    DIV = '/' ;
}

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * LEXER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

ID  : ('a'..'z' | 'A' .. 'Z' | '0' .. '9')+ ;

WHITESPACE : ( '\t' | ' ' | '\r' | '\n'| '\u000C' )+    { Skip(); } ;

/*------------------------------------------------------------------
 * PARSER RULES
 *------------------------------------------------------------------*/

expr : multExpr ((PLUS | MINUS)^ multExpr)*;

multExpr : atom ((MULT | DIV)^ atom )*;

atom : ID
     | '(' expr ')' -> expr;
```

Now I have some pre-defined type for creating tree structure:

```
public class Expr { }

public class SimpleExpr : Expr
{
    public SimpleExpr(string name) { ... }
}

public enum BinaryExprType
{
    Plus,
    Minus,
    Multiply,
    Divide
}

public class BinaryExpr : Expr
{
    public BinaryExpr(Expr left, BinaryExprType op, Expr right) { ... }
}
```

I know we can write some code to convert a `CommonTree` to `Expr` tree, but I'd like to rewrite directly to the custom types like:

```
atom returns [Expr e]
    : ID { $e = new SimpleExpr($ID.text); }
    | '(' expr ')' { $e = $expr.e; };

expr returns [Expr e]
    : /* ??? */;

multExpr returns [Expr e]
    : /* ??? */;
```

But how should I do for `expr` and `multExpr` to create `BinaryExpr` with proper `BinaryExprType`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this (untested!):

```
expr returns [Expr e]
 : m1=multExpr         {$e = $m1.e;} 
   ( PLUS m2=multExpr  {$e = new BinaryExpr($expr.e, BinaryExprType.Plus, $m2.e);}
   | MINUS m2=multExpr {$e = new BinaryExpr($expr.e, BinaryExprType.Minus, $m2.e);}
   )*
 ;

multExpr returns [Expr e]
 : a1=atom        {$e = $a1.e;}
   ( MULT a2=atom {$e = new BinaryExpr($multExpr.e, BinaryExprType.Multiply, $a2.e);}
   | DIV a2=atom  {$e = new BinaryExpr($multExpr.e, BinaryExprType.Divide, $a2.e);}
   )*
 ;

atom returns [Expr e]
 : ID           {$e = new SimpleExpr($ID.text);}
 | '(' expr ')' {$e = $expr.e;}
 ;
```

The trick is to recursively use the rule itself in the binary expressions: the `$expr.e` and `$multExpr.e` in `new BinaryExpr(...)`.